# highlight fieldset without using css

Tags: jquery

Having a form separated in fieldset I'd like to highlight the fieldset in which the user is operating, this may be a solution:

```
<script>
    $().ready(function() {
        $('form :input').focus(function() {
            $(this).closest('fieldset').addClass('f1');
        });

        $('form :input').blur(function() {
            $(this).closest('fieldset').removeClass('f1');
        });
    });
</script>
```

where f1 is a css class

```
.f1 {
    background-color: grey;
    transition: 2s;
}
```

But I'd like to know if exists a solution that doesn't use css class, I've tried to use the animate() function without the wanted outcome.

Comment: If you're animating colours, you will need to load [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) to do so - jQuery library itself does not support animating colours, just numeric values (e.g. width, height, margin, padding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to load jQuery UI as well in order to animate colours — it should be noted that the `.animation()` function in jQuery UI does **not** support CSS colour names. You will have to use hexadecimal values, `rgb[a]()`, `hsl()` and etc.

```
$(function () {
    $('form :input').focus(function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').stop(true,true).animate({
            "background-color": "#808080" // CSS hex color equivalent of grey
        },2000);
    });

    $('form :input').blur(function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').stop(true,true)..animate({
            "background-color": "transparent"
        },2000);
    });
});
```

**Note:** `.stop(true,true)` is used before the `.animate()` method to ensure that the animation queue does not end up in a stack if a user quickly focuses in and blurs out of the inputs.

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/8wRhG/

---

However, I would not recommend loading jQuery UI just for the sake of colour animation. May I kindly suggest using CSS transition plus setting the fieldset background using JS instead?

```
$(function () {
    $('form :input').focus(function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').css({
            "background-color": "#808080"
        });
    });

    $('form :input').blur(function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').css({
            "background-color": "transparent"
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
form fieldset input {
    transition: background-color 2s linear;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/8wRhG/4/